# EL expression not evaluated in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

I have simple servlet that passes parameter to jsp file.
Here is the code:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("userName", userName);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The page welcome.jsp contains:

```
<body>
<h3 align="center">Welcome ${userName}!!!</h3>

<a href="index.jsp">go back</a>
</body>
```

The index.jsp:

```
<form method="post" action="check">
Name <input type="text" name="userName" >
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Finally web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>check</servlet-name>
    <display-name>check</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>check</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/check</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Problem is that parameter is not passed to welcome.jsp. I still see

> $userName

What is the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

You can do
`<h3 align="center">Welcome <%=(String)session.getAttribute("userName")%>!!!</h3>` instead of
`<h3 align="center">Welcome ${userName}!!!</h3>`